# How can I filter an array which has an array in it and based on particular condition from that internal array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

From the object below, I just want all the items array which has UnitCharge greater than 0. Can this be done using filter and reduce methods of javascript and how?

```js
[{
    "Description": "xyz",
    "items": [{
        "itemid": 319,
        "itemDescription": "bucket",
        "UnitCharge": 10
      },
      {
        "itemid": 320,
        "itemDescription": "mug",
        "UnitCharge": 100
      },
      {
        "itemid": 349,
        "itemDescription": "Jug",
        "UnitCharge": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Description": "xyz2",
    "items": [{
        "itemid": 301,
        "itemDescription": "chair",
        "UnitCharge": 10
      },
      {
        "itemid": 382,
        "itemDescription": "table",
        "UnitCharge": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to apply filter on every items object. can anyone help me with that

Updated the expected result :

```
[{
    "Description": "xyz",
    "items": [{
        "itemid": 319,
        "itemDescription": "bucket",
        "UnitCharge": 10
      },
      {
        "itemid": 320,
        "itemDescription": "mug",
        "UnitCharge": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Description": "xyz2",
    "items": [{
        "itemid": 301,
        "itemDescription": "chair",
        "UnitCharge": 10
      }
    ]
  }
```

]

Comment: please add a wanted result and the code, you tried.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: expected result :
"filteredItems": [
           
{
                "itemid": 319,
                "itemDescription": "bucket",
                "UnitCharge": 10
            },
            {
                "itemid": 320,
                "itemDescription": "mug",
                "UnitCharge": 100
            },
           {
                "itemid": 301,
                "itemDescription": "chair",
                "UnitCharge": 10
            }
]

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting unformatted code in comments. I copied the results for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**ES6 & above**

```js
let arr = [{"Description":"xyz","items":[{"itemid":319,"itemDescription":"bucket","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":320,"itemDescription":"mug","UnitCharge":100},{"itemid":349,"itemDescription":"Jug","UnitCharge":0}]},{"Description":"xyz2","items":[{"itemid":301,"itemDescription":"chair","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":382,"itemDescription":"table","UnitCharge":0}]}];

let result = arr.reduce((a,c) => [...a, ...c.items.filter(v => v.UnitCharge > 0)], []);
console.log(result);
```

**ES5**

```js
let arr = [{"Description":"xyz","items":[{"itemid":319,"itemDescription":"bucket","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":320,"itemDescription":"mug","UnitCharge":100},{"itemid":349,"itemDescription":"Jug","UnitCharge":0}]},{"Description":"xyz2","items":[{"itemid":301,"itemDescription":"chair","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":382,"itemDescription":"table","UnitCharge":0}]}];

let result = arr.reduce(function(a,c){
  return a.concat(c.items.filter(function(v){
    return v.UnitCharge > 0
  }));
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**

```js
let arr = [{"Description":"xyz","items":[{"itemid":319,"itemDescription":"bucket","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":320,"itemDescription":"mug","UnitCharge":100},{"itemid":349,"itemDescription":"Jug","UnitCharge":0}]},{"Description":"xyz2","items":[{"itemid":301,"itemDescription":"chair","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":382,"itemDescription":"table","UnitCharge":0}]}];

let result = arr.map(({items, ...rest}) => ({...rest, items:items.filter(v => v.UnitCharge > 0)}));
console.log(result);
```

**EDIT 2**

```js
let arr = [{"Description":"xyz","items":[{"itemid":319,"itemDescription":"bucket","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":320,"itemDescription":"mug","UnitCharge":100},{"itemid":349,"itemDescription":"Jug","UnitCharge":0}]},{"Description":"xyz2","items":[{"itemid":301,"itemDescription":"chair","UnitCharge":10},{"itemid":382,"itemDescription":"table","UnitCharge":0}]}];

let result = arr.map(({items, ...rest}) => ({...rest, items:items.filter(v => v.UnitCharge > 0)})).filter(v => v.items.length > 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have updated the expected result. can you help me with this?

Comment: @AzizNagpurwala - Do you want to update the existing array or create a new one?

Comment: There is one problem with the updated solution. If the second object "Description": "xyz2" does not have any item with unit charge > 0, then that complete object should not be the part of result. Can you help?

Comment: @AzizNagpurwala - You can simply use `filter` for that. See my second edit for it.

Comment: Can I get description as a part of items array example description should be part of itemId 319 and 320 as well. Any suggestions

Comment: Do you want to copy description xyz to every item? Do you wish to update the existing objects too?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrayObj=[{
    "Description": "xyz",
    "items": [{
        "itemid": 319,
        "itemDescription": "bucket",
        "UnitCharge": 10
      },
      {
        "itemid": 320,
        "itemDescription": "mug",
        "UnitCharge": 100
      },
      {
        "itemid": 349,
        "itemDescription": "Jug",
        "UnitCharge": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Description": "xyz2",
    "items": [{
        "itemid": 301,
        "itemDescription": "chair",
        "UnitCharge": 10
      },
      {
        "itemid": 382,
        "itemDescription": "table",
        "UnitCharge": 0
      }
    ]
  }
];
console.log("sdd");
for (var i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++) {
    var item=arrayObj[i].items;
    for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
  if(item[j].UnitCharge>10) alert( item[j].UnitCharge)
    }
    //Do something
}
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers above work fine, but I prefer to use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead these days for such scenarios. It's intuitive and elegant. The catch is flatMap doesn't work in Microsoft's ecosystem, so **no IE/Edge support for now**, but I am lucky enough to not have to support those most of the time.

```
array.flatMap(record => record.items.filter(item => item.UnitCharge > 0))
```